# Нужна помощь с ES6 модулями

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babel

Написал небольшую библиотеку и теперь пытаюсь перевести её на ES6 но и сделать версию для обычного использования, чтобы просто подключить тег скрипта и использовать.
Использую webpack и babel-loader.
Код из основного файла библиотеки:

```
'use strict';

import helpers from './lib/helpers';
import styles from './lib/styles';
import color from './lib/color';
import decorators from './lib/decorators';
import forms from './lib/forms';
import DOM from './lib/DOM';
import namespace from './lib/namespace';
import addMethod from './lib/addMethod';

var eclipse = {
    globals: {},
    storage: {
        dropdowns: [],
        bundles: [],
        spinners: [],
        staticTabs: [],
        adaptiveTabs: [],
        searches: [],
        cache: {}
    },
    helpers: helpers,
    styles: styles,
    color: color,
    decorators: decorators,
    forms: forms,
    DOM: DOM,
    modules: {}
};

eclipse.namespace = namespace.bind(eclipse);
eclipse.addMethod = addMethod.bind(eclipse);

export default eclipse;
```

Настройки webpack:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './eclipse.js',
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'eclipse.js',
        library: 'eclipse',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: false
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                },
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: null
};
```

Вроде все собирается хорошо, но есть одна проблема. При обычно подключении через тег скрипта в глобальную область попадает объект:

```
{
    __esModule: true,
    default: мой объект библиотеки eclipse
}
```

Получается что я не могу сделать так

```
eclipse.someMethod
```

Приходится так:

```
eclipse.default.someMethod
```

Как можно это обойти. Я с webpack не знаком особо. Я понимаю что такое происходит из-за "export default eclipse;", но как это обойти не знаю. Можно конечно написать "module.exports = eclipse;" но может есть другой способ? Может вообще мой способ сборки не подходит? Ничего подобного не делал раньше, поэтому может сделал глупости.
Еще использую Gulp, но наверно его код вряд-ли тут нужен.

Comment: `webpack` - продукт на любителя. Твой gulp и без него прекрасно справится.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых export.default делает не webpack а транспайлер. 
 В одном из [ответах](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/706) на гитхабе говорится, что:

> webpack использует по стандарту вызов reqire, и если вы конвертируете в es5, он оборачивает import используя .default и возвращает обратно на export

И там как раз предлагают сделать `module.exports = Library;`.

Ещё как вариант попробуйте сделать

```
 export { foo as myFoo } from 'src/other_module';
```

Comment: Получилось с последним вариантом?

Comment: Оставил module.exports. А второй вариант не пойму, export from? Import наверное?

Comment: Это называется re-exporting детально можно туту почитать http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: я так не пробовал делать, но  можно покрутить варианты с "as" export { D as default };

Comment: не получился такой вариант, оставил module.exports. Спасибо за помощь